# Is there a php wrapper for Google Visualisation API?

Tags: php, graph, wrapper

i'd like to make a php wrapper for Google Visualisation API .. I mean, a simple way to transform a php array to a nice piece of javascript to make a graph by Google API ..

But of course i'm almost sure somebody has already created such a thing .. but i can't find ..

does it exist ? open source preferred

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

Check here

http://googlecode.blogspot.com/2008/08/google-visualization-api-now-in-php.html

Answer (score 0):

did u read [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

```
<?php
$arr = array ('a'=>1,'b'=>2,'c'=>3,'d'=>4,'e'=>5);

echo json_encode($arr);
?>
//output array => {"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}
```

if you want output as an **object** then use

```
json_encode($b, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

Comment: sure but the conversion is not the only thing i need to do : i want to have a function like "showGraph($myarray);" and it converts that a a nice JS script which takes myarray and gives a full Google API graph